# scanf() not returning the correct number of arguments

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write a simple program that will take input about people in this format:

```
 name,age,gender,info
```

Here is the code so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main() {
    char name[10];
    int age;
    char gender[2];
    char info[50];

    while(scanf("%9s,%i,%1s,%49[^\n]", name, &age, gender, info) == 4)
    puts("Success");

    return 0;
 }
```

So at the terminal I enter something like: `bob,10,M,likes cheese` but it does not print out the success message, so I guess the condition at the while loop failed.

So add this code to check the number of arguments:

```
int i = scanf("%9s,%i,%1s,%49[^\n]", name, &age, gender, info);
printf("%i", i);
```

and when I enter bob,10,M,likes cheese again, it prints out 1.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: There is no need for `scanf`, and indeed this question gives evidence that `scanf` is too complex to ever be used reliably.  Use `fgets` and tokenize the string.  It's probably easier to learn how to do that than it is to learn to use `scanf` properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%9s` will consume input until it finds white-space, reaches the specified length (9) or the end of the string, which, in this case, will consume `bob,10,M,` instead of just `bob`.

[Test](http://ideone.com/Gz7amD).

Try `%9[^,],%i,%1s,%49[^\n]` instead.

[Test](http://ideone.com/lOJZhM).

Also, since gender is 1 character, you may as well make it a `char` and use `%c` instead of `%1s` (unless it's optional).

[Test](http://ideone.com/lFqTYC).